# How to integrate android ndk to eclipse in ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, installation

I am very new to android ndk. Can you please tell me how to step-by-step install android ndk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the links [Android NDK r7](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) and [What is the NDK?](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) from the developer's guide tell you all you need to know?

Answer (score -1):

1. Installation of Eclipse IDE, Oracle Java JRE, Android SDK and Android Developer Tool (ADT, a special Eclipse plug-in)
2. Setting up Eclipse IDE with Android SDK and Android Developer Tool.
3. Writing a simple Android Application: "Hello Android".
4. Testing Android application using Android Virtual Device.

Comment: i need a guide to do all of these. I have eclipse an integrated android sdk right now. But i dont know how  to install and use ndk on linux

Comment: Question is related to installing "N"DK, not "S"DK